# Where to find file PythonScriptWrapper.PY?

Tags: python, powerbi

I try to start using Python in PowerBI but whatever I do I get message "ADO.NET: Python script error.
 C:/Users/XXXXX/AppData/Local/anaconda3/envs/py36/python.exe: can't open file 'PythonScriptWrapper.PY': [Errno 2] No such file or directory".

I am using anaconda. Where is the PythonScriptWrapper.PY supposed to be?

Tried also to use Python 3.6 as read that Power BI would not support 3.7 but actually here https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/python-visualizations-in-power-bi-service/ it says 3.7.1 is supported.

I installed Anaconda again. NO success. Installed pandas, numpy, matplotlib

Comment: Found the solution: It is a temporary file created by Power BI and I had not configured the temporary storage location to a writable temp folder so it was never created. Changed the temporary storage location and it works now.

Comment: Did you change your storage location to something special? Struggling with the same issue

Comment: @Trinity Yes where and how did you change the temporary storage location? What did you change it to?